linux extraction for log output not grouping correctly
I have a text file in which command output is copied. I need to parse the text files in separate columns.
I have the below data in a text file port.txt
NAME---SERIALNUMBER------FREE_PORTS
tx1    s4tx999d          0/1, 0/4,0/6
                         0/9,0/11
tx2    s4tx998f          1/2,0/9,,1/3
                         0/8,0/11,
                         1/7
tx3    s4tx997v          0/9

I require the output in the below format
NAME|SERIALNUMBER|FREE_PORTS
tx1|s4tx999d|0/1,0/4,0/6,0/9,0/11
tx2|s4tx998f|1/2,0/9,1/3,0/8,0/11,1/7
tx3|s4tx997v|0/9

I tried to use the below command, but it does not aggregate all free_ports in a single row
cat ports.txt | cut -c1-5 -- For The Name
cat ports.txt | cut -c6-13 -- For SERIALNUMBER
cat ports.txt | cut -14-23 -- For Free ports


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E ':a;$!N;s/\n\s+/,/;ta;s/,+ ?/,/g;s/[ -]+/|/g;P;D' file

Append the next line unless that line is already the last line.
If the pattern space contains a newline followed by one or more white space, replace the newline and spaces by a comma and go again as above.
Otherwise, replace multiple commas followed by a possible space by a single comma and replace multiple spaces/dashes by |'s.
Print up to and including the first newline.
Delete up to and including the first newline.
Repeat.

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let port.txt content be
NAME---SERIALNUMBER------FREE_PORTS
tx1    s4tx999d          0/1, 0/4,0/6
                         0/9,0/11
tx2    s4tx998f          1/2,0/9,,1/3
                         0/8,0/11,
                         1/7
tx3    s4tx997v          0/9

then
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n";ORS=""}{gsub(/\n[ \t]+/,",");gsub(/[ \t-]{3,}/,"|");print}' port.txt

gives output
NAME|SERIALNUMBER|FREE_PORTS
tx1|s4tx999d|0/1, 0/4,0/6,0/9,0/11
tx2|s4tx998f|1/2,0/9,,1/3,0/8,0/11,,1/7
tx3|s4tx997v|0/9

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that blank line (i.e. two subsequent newlines) is row separator (RS), thus whole file is treated as single row. Then I use gsub, 1st does turn ports spanning multiple lines into single line, 2nd is used to change separator (space, TAB or dash, 3 or more examples) into | shearing field. Then I use print to output changed content, observe that I set output field separator (OFS) to empty line as otherwise trailing newline would be added. Observe that space-prefix and empty-string ports are preserved if you must purge them AT ANY PRICE then add 3rd gsub to do so.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Using any POSIX awk:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="|" }
NR == 1 { gsub(/-+/,OFS); print; next }
/^[^[:space:]]/ { prt(); rec = $0; next }
{ rec = rec " " $0 }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( rec != "" ) {
        sub(/[[:space:]]+/,OFS,rec)
        sub(/[[:space:]]+/,OFS,rec)
        gsub(/[[:space:],]+/,",",rec)
        print rec
    }
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file
NAME|SERIALNUMBER|FREE_PORTS
tx1|s4tx999d|0/1,0/4,0/6,0/9,0/11
tx2|s4tx998f|1/2,0/9,1/3,0/8,0/11,1/7
tx3|s4tx997v|0/9


Solution in TXR
$ txr table.txr data
NAME|SERIALNUMBER|FREE_PORTS
tx1|s4tx999d|0/1,0/4,0/6,0/9,0/11
tx2|s4tx998f|1/2,0/9,1/3,0/8,0/11,1/7
tx3|s4tx997v|0/9

Code in table.txr:
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
@ah@/-+/@bh@/-+/@ch
@  (or)
@{ah 7}@{bh           18}@(coll)@{ch /[^, ]+/}@(end)
@  (end)
@  (collect :gap 0 :vars (c))
                         @(coll)@{c /[^, ]+/}@(end)
@  (end)
@  (do (put-line `@ah|@bh|@{(append ch . c) ","}`))
@(end)

In color:

